# Hibernate: Pass array of Entities to PostgreSql function

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, stored-functions

```
Hibernate: 5.4.0.Final
PostgreSql: 9.6.6 (It would be an option to upgrade to latest version)
```

I have tables `A`, `B` and `C`. And the following postgresql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myFunction(param1 "A"[], param2 "B") RETURNS SETOF "C" AS $$
    BEGIN
......
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So basicly, I want to pass an array of records from table `A` and a single record of `B`. As result, I want a list of records from table `C`. I want to call this function from hibernate. Note that the passed entities from table `A` are not persistent so it is not an option to pass an array of ids. Instead I want to pass the whole (not persistent) entities.

My current hibernate code looks like this:

```
ProcedureCall call = session.createStoredProcedureCall("myFunction");

call.registerParameter(1, <Type?>, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(listOfEntities);
call.registerParameter(2, EntityForTableB.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(entityForTableB);

((ResultSetOutput)call.getOutputs().getCurrent()).getResultList();
```

I cannot identify the right way to pass the function parameters. Currently, I get this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Function myFunction(bytea, bytea) does not exist
```

What would be the correct way to handle this? I found solutions where the entities are transformed to json format but it looked complicated. Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Even with array support in hibernate, you cannot use array of `record` or any non-basic type. Neither the JDBC driver, nor the Postgres server are equipped to handle arrays of complex types.

Comment: I got it implemented using json. Code got bloated up and it seems to be quite performance hit. Dunno if this can be improved. Have not yet looked into it much more.